# add data to table periodically in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have income table which contain recurrence field. Now if user select recurrence_type as "Monthly" or "Daily" then I have to add row into income table "daily" or "monthly" . Is there any way in Mysql which will add data periodically into table ? I am using Django Framework for developing web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know there is no such function in MySQL. Even if MySQL could do it, this should not be its job. Such functions should be part of the business logic in your application.

The normal way is to setup the cron job in server. The cron job will wake up at the time you set, and then call your python script or SQL to fulfil the adding data work. And scripts are much better than direct SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Used django-celery package and created job in it to update the data periodically